# Possible to iterate over a column or row of GridLayout contents in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm building a tic-tac-toe game and want to make the logic a bit less repetitive. I'm currently checking all possible win conditions for each clicked spot by doing the following:

```
public static boolean isCompleted(int position, ImageView[] blocks) {
    GameLogic.blocks = blocks;
    boolean isComplete = false;
    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            isComplete = areSameInSet(1, 2, 3) ||
                    areSameInSet(1, 4, 7) ||
                    areSameInSet(1, 5, 9);
            break;
```

And sending them to this method, which checks a numeric value, 0 for circle and 1 for cross, that gets set on a click:

```
private static boolean areSameInSet(int first, int second, int third) {
    boolean value = blocks[first - 1].getId() == blocks[second - 1].getId() &&
            blocks[second - 1].getId() == blocks[third - 1].getId();
```

Is it possible to look at the entire row or column of this gridview, instead of this custom method that needs 3 different arguments every time?

I've tried to look at TableView to see if this is a better option, but I'm having trouble seeing any way in that route either.

Ideally I can run a method like, checkSum(row, column) that sums to check for 3 or -3 (one player denoted by 1 and one by -1), with some special conditions for the diagonals.

Edit:
I'm not completely sure what you mean, but the grid is static, and each imageview inside takes up one spot, and doesn't move from it.

```
  <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

Followed by nine nested ImageViews, one of which is like so:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/block1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: If your column number is fixed, you can do this in `getView(position)`. You will get the position. Can you post your grid view code for more understanding?

Comment: I edited in the code. Looking through getView documentation, I'm having a hard time understanding how you would do so. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

If your column number is fixed, you can do this in `getView(position)`. You will get the position.

You can find the example for [custom grid view](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/material-design/android-custom-gridview-example-image-text/) in the link

CustomAdapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    String [] result;
    Context context;
    int [] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] osNameList, int[] osImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=osNameList;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=osImages;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView os_text;
        ImageView os_img;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_gridlayout, null);
        holder.os_text =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.os_texts);
        holder.os_img =(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.os_images);

        holder.os_text.setText(result[position]);
        holder.os_img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

In your activity,

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, String[] your_data, int[] img_arr);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

As you mentioned, your column is 3, and row count is 3.
then the positions `0, 1, 2` indicates 1st row,
`3, 4, 5` indicates 2nd row,
`6, 7, 8` indicates 3rd row.

Answer (score 0):

Because your grid is fixed, the positions never change so you basically have items with indices:

0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8

You can map your data to a 2D array that has its indices:
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2)
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2)
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2)

This way you can check for entire rows and columns. For the first diagonal you can check for the condition that both indices are equal (0,0), (1,1), (2,2). And for the second diagonal you can check that the sum of the indices is 2 (2,0), (1, 1), (0, 2).